# How to set the vm heapsize of android instrumentation tests from command line

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-instrumentation

I am running tests on AndroidJunitRunner on an emulator.

This is part of a ci run

The emulator is created with the following commands:

> echo no | avdmanager create avd -n android29 -k 'system-images;android-29;default;x86' --force

> emulator -gpu swiftshader_indirect -no-window -feature GLESDynamicVersion -avd android29 -memory 3072 -partition-size 2048 -cache-size 2048 >/dev/null 2>&1 &

I am getting errors:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 9437192 byte allocation with 4724576 free bytes and 4613KB until OOM, target footprint 16777216, growth limit
> 16777216

It looks like the heap size of the junit runner is 16MB. Why is this ? How do i control this? I am googling for hours and don't find where i can define the heap size.

Answer (score 2):

Update: This answer below may not be correct. The most important switch is -memory but there is an upper limit of 576MB in android emulator 29: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/08/emulator-2919-canary.html?hl=th

I would be happy to find a source where this heap calculation is explained.

Old answer:
I found a way.

There is a config file under .android which contains the heap size. it can be manipulated easily.

I manipulate it as part of github actions:

```
 async function fixIni(version, sizeInMb){
const homedir = require('os').homedir();
    const path = `${homedir}/.android/avd/android${version}.avd/config.ini`
    const content = await fs.promises.readFile(path, "utf8")
    const fixed = content.split("\n").map(line => line.startsWith("vm.heapSize=")? `vm.heapSize=${sizeInMb}M`: line)
    await fs.promises.writeFile(path,fixed.join("\n"))
}
```

this has to be run after avdmanager creates avd and before emulator is launched

Comment: Did this work to fix the instrumentation tests for you? I get a similar error but the end of that line says `VmSize 1151480 kB`, and I'm thinking if it's already 1124 MB why is the growth limit just 16MB and if this option changes that.

Comment: It is a sporadic error and I need the fix deployed more time to have a definite answer. I think I will need it at least 2 more weeks. There is a difference between the memory of emulator and the heap size of each process. I verified with dumpsysthat the instrumentation ram size grew to what I wanted but let's see if there won't be any errors

Comment: Ah, you're right. VmSize is not the same as the VM heap size. I found that I wasn't able to get more than 576MB heap size no matter how I tweaked the `vm.heapSize` value. I was using a Nexus 5X hardware profile though. Then again, compared to 16 MB, this should be a lot of improvement :) Please share if this occurs again. I will share some findings too!

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. System server still ends up crashing and the growth limit for it is still 16 MB strangely.

Comment: i think you are right. please look at https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/08/emulator-2919-canary.html?hl=th 
Restricted VM heap size calculation. 576 MB is now the maximum allowed.
so even when playing with the -memory switch of emulator or playing around with vm.heapsize you won't get out more than 576MB. i would like to find a place where these calculations are explained

Comment: @AfzalN did you find a solution? I am in a similar situation. Regards

Comment: No, sorry @Jeremad. We moved our UI test setup to a real device on Firebase test lab. Way more reliable. :(

Comment: @AfzalN I found this interesting read https://rainforest.engineering/2021-04-16-android-heap-race/
It helped me a bit circle around my issue

Comment: Thanks! I guess that works if you have root in the emulator. Unfortunately, Google Play emulators don't have root so I guess this is impossible then. Wonder if the new ATD emulators are any better.

Comment: Yeah, I use root and restart zygote to workaround the issue. I mostly hope this race condition gets eventually fixed.